# ng-cordova.js:2483 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working in Ionic project. In order to use the scanner QR code, I use ng-cordova. I downloaded the ng-cordova.js  from this website : http://ngcordova.com/build/

When I run the project with the command Ionic serve, on my console I get the syntax error in javascript file : ng-cordova.js:2483 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

the row 2483 of ng-cordova.js has this code:

```
Not Found// install  :     cordova plugin add https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro.git
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: The row is var q = $q.defer(); 
I guess you do not have a recent version. I suggest you to download it via GitHub.

Comment: Do you have the `admob-pro` plugin installed?

Comment: Hi Matheno,
as you suggest, i downloaded the library with bower.
Now  I haven't this error. Thanks!